# Custom fields "on demand"

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform, custom-field

I've got an article that's a simple event. I don't need any event management extension because

I used joomla custom fields to associate to each event some info like speakers, date, ....

One info associated with each event it's called "tracks". On event can have none to several tracks associated. Since it's not possible to know how many tracks there will be associated with the event, I'd like to have a custom text field, where the admin would put the track name, and if there were more tracks he could click a button "add" (for example) to add another field to fill with another track name.

How could this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have used jform then You can use Subform field.
[Read here more about Subform repeatable field](https://techjoomla.com/developers-blogs/joomla-development/using-sub-forms-to-create-repeatable-fields)

Answer (score 0):

I did not look into Custom fields component so far, but Joomla have [repeatable](https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type) field as a standard, so I believe it should be in the list. It does exactly what you ask.